# Functionality of Add/Update, Replace, Delete clarity needed

Tags: magento2

What's the actual functionality difference during csv  import of

1) Add/Update

2) Replace

3) Delete- Delete just deletes the products imported in the csv during import

I am confused as for eg: If there are 10 products for importing, i make change for 5 products and select Add/Update, Will all the 5 ids or 10 ids be saved in backend or only those updated ones will be saved over existing ones.

If i select Replace, what exactly happens?

Clarity required!

Comment: if I need to change the category which options should I choose? I would need to change from one to another,
thanks,
Cris.

Answer (score 8):

**Import products:**

(1)**Add/Update Product**:
   Product are added into admin **catalog -> product** and if any update in product row for any attibute those are updated and new row are added to product catalog.

**In This scenario,** if product is already exist, at that time content are updated for product and if product is not already available in catalog, create new product.

(2)**Replace**: `Replace works as Add/Update product functionlity but its remove old product and generate new product`.

**If you have already product with sku ABC and its product id is 1, and you can choose Replace from dropdown at import time, new Product ABC are generated with new product id 2 so remove product with id 1 and generate new product with new id.**

(3)**Delete**: `Remove all product from catalog, match with given sku from csv file.`

Please let me know for any issue.

Comment: Hi @rakesh can you help me regarding  this issue  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239607/magento-2-how-to-avoid-numbers-for-color-attribute-values

Comment: When we use replace for the simple product (children) is any effect will happen to configurable product?