# Magento 2 how to avoid ids for color attribute values?

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute, product-import

I have **imported** products in magento 2 with **color** and **size** using csv, but we have **deleted** previous **color values** and did re-index and re-again  we have created **new color** values for the same **color** attribute and updated to the products, here something went wrong i am not sure facing one issue i.e when we **export** the data the **color values** are appearing with numbers (ids).

Could you please any on advise how to fix ?

```
Is this issue fix with Replace products with CSV?
```

please refer the screenshot below:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();

foreach($products as $product)
{

$col =$product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

}